# Batch File: Escaping ! within For Loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, escaping

I am trying to create a for loop that will go through a directory and run an ffmpeg command to all files within that directory. My problem is that some of the files have `!` in their name which causes problems when using delayed expansion. I have researched many solutions and none of them are getting me anywhere. Currently I can echo the file names with the `!` included, but I cannot seem to pass the file name with the `!` into my for loop as the delayed expansion effectively removes the `!`.

Here is my batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in ("Y:\Samples\Test Videos\*.mkv") do (
    set "filename=%%~nxf"
    ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec copy -vbsf h264_changesps=level=40 -vbsf h264_changesps=fps=24000:1001 "E:\Converted\!filename!"
)
pause
```

This works fine for all files without the `!` in the name. If I use a batch script like this:

```
@echo off
for %%f in ("Y:\Samples\Test Videos\*.mkv") do (
   call :command "%%f"
)
pause

:command
set "fname=%~nx1"
set "fpath=%~dpnx1"
echo %fname%
ffmpeg -i %fpath% -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec copy -vbsf h264_changesps=level=40 -vbsf h264_changesps=fps=24000:1001 "E:\Converted\%fname%"
```

Then I can get the file names and full paths to echo with the `!` included, but the ffmpeg command referencing `%fname%` and `%fpath%` returns a `No such file or directory` message. If I add in `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` just after the echo off and change the ffmpeg string to have `!` instead of `%`, then I again get the `No such file or directory` message.

I know that in a `FOR` loop everything in the `DO` part of the statement gets expanded before everything else which is why I need to use delayed expansion, but how can I use that and still use file names that contain `!`? Is there a way to get the first batch to accept files that have the `!` in the name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is not to use delayed expansion.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set ffmpegArguments=-vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec copy -vbsf h264_changesps=level=40 -vbsf h264_changesps=fps=24000:1001

    for %%f in ("Y:\Samples\Test Videos\*.mkv") do (
        ffmpeg -i "%%f" %ffmpegArguments% "E:\Converted\%%~nxf" 
    )
    pause
```

There is not any need to assign the information retrieved from the `for` replaceable parameter to a variable, just use the retrieved value

Comment: You forgot to mention there is no need for CALL. The CALL will corrupt any name that contains `^`. Your code should work in all cases.

Comment: Excellent work MC ND! It's simple and makes so much sense in hindsight!

Answer (score 0):

```
:command

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "fname=%~nx1"
set "fpath=%~dpnx1"
echo %fname%
ffmpeg -i %fpath% -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec copy -vbsf h264_changesps=level=40 -vbsf h264_changesps=fps=24000:1001 "E:\Converted\%fname%"

ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF
```

should fix your problem by disabling the delayedexpansion while `!` is a literal character.

I add the `goto` out of habit so I don't have to remember about it if I add a new subroutine.

Comment: Your's doesn't work because `%fpath%` needs to be in quotes, `"%fpath%"`. The interesting thing for me is that your answer only varies from mine with adding in `DisableDelayedExpansion`, but it turns out that it doesn't even need that. I can get it working with just putting `%fpath%` in quotes. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I posted too soon! I finally got it working!

It turns out that in the second script using `%fpath%` for the ffmpeg input only gets the filepath up until the first space where it truncates (because I didn't have it in quotes). After putting `%fpath%` in quotes, the script works with files that have `!` in the name!  Here it is:

```
@echo off
for %%f in ("Y:\Samples\Test Videos\*.mkv") do (
   call :command "%%f"
)

:command
set "fname=%~nx1"
set "fpath=%~dpnx1"
ffmpeg -i "%fpath%" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec copy -vbsf h264_changesps=level=40 -vbsf h264_changesps=fps=24000:1001 "E:\Converted\%fname%"
```

Comment: You managed to fix your code, but I don't think you fully understand why. Yes, you must quote `"%fpath%"`, but it is also critical that delayed expansion be disabled when your FOR loop expands `%%f` if the value might contain `!`. The default is for delayed expansion to be disabled, but your original code had it enabled. Your code in this answer works  because you do not enable delayed expansion.

Comment: You still have the potential for failure. If a file path contains the `^` character, then the CALL will double the quoted `^` into `^^`, and your command will fail. [MC ND has a correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43435510/1012053) that should work in all cases - no delayed expansion, no CALL, and properly quoted arguments.